# lxterminal does not show output until mouse/keyboard command

Tags: lubuntu, lxterminal

I installed and did all updates for Lubuntu 18.04.1 (64bit)

When running Lxterminal, after typing a command and pressing enter, I get no output. However if I move the mouse over the terminal window, or type another key on the keyboard, the window seems to 'refresh' and show the output up to date.

This is extremely annoying obviously, does anyone know what would be causing this and how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with a setting in the Openbox Configuration Manager. Go to preferences > Openbox Configuration Manager > Mouse, and uncheck the box that says focus windows. You may have to reboot for it to take effect.